# Python / Django как запустить стороннее приложение в отдельном потоке?

Tags: python, django, unix

Требуется на запрос в Django запустить приложение, которое должно продолжить работу после того, как хендлер отработает.

Для этого написал следущую строку os.system("programName &").
В итоге запрос выдает connection timeout.

Comment: Используйте очередь заданий. Например, [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/index.html).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, спасибо! Погуглю на этот счет.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вы что? Использовать селери для этого? оверкил да и сложно, если человек задает такие вопросы

Comment: @Fexolm конкретно по вашей таске, существует модуль multiprocessing

Comment: @Reishin, спасибо за ваш комментарий. Но боюсь, что с multiprocessing у меня та же проблема. (интересно, что на локальной машине она не проявляется. Реквесты проходят спокойно.)
А при запуске на сервере с Nginx и uwsgi запросы как-будто лочатся и ждут, пока приложение завершит работу

`t = mp.Process(target=os.system, args=['bash ....'])
t.start()`

вот такой код я написал

Comment: @Fexolm надо сразу писать про uwsgi, т.к. там своеобразный питон работает ))

Comment: @Reishin, понятно. Не знал, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена с помощью добавления

`close-on-exec = true` в uwsgi.ini